# Find the dimension of the vector space $R[x]/J$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb R[x]$ be the ring of polynomials in the indeterminate $x$ over the ﬁeld
of real numbers and let $J$ be the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^3 − x$. Find the dimension of the vector space $\mathbb R[x]/J$.

---

Any element of $\mathbb R[x]/J$ is looks like $$ax^2+bx+c+(x^3 − x).$$ since {$1,x,x^2$} generates $ax^2+bx+c$, so answer will be $3$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes...but: can you prove the different claims you made?

Comment: You also need to show that the set $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $f \in R[x]$ is monic of degree $n$, then polynomial division is exactly the statement that $\overline{1},\overline{x},\dotsc,\overline{x^{n-1}}$ is an $R$-basis of $R[x]/(f)$.